# Why does leetcode accept code which wouldnt usually be ran in an IDE?

Tags: c++

Okay so the following class was accepted and ran in the Two sum problem in leetcode:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {

        vector<int> arr(2);

        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
            for(int j = i+1; j < nums.size(); j++){
                if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                    arr[0] = i;
                    arr[1] = j;
                } 

            }
        }
            return arr;
    }
};
```

I then tried to use this within my IDE (codeblocks), but i have to make the vector nums constant... why do i have to do this in codeblocks but leetcode somehow ignores this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(const vector<int>& nums, int target) {

        vector<int> arr(2);

        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
            for(int j = i+1; j < nums.size(); j++){
                if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                    arr[0] = i;
                    arr[1] = j;
                }

            }
        }
            return arr;
    }
};

int main() {

Solution solution;
solution.twoSum({2,7,11,15},9);

}
```

---

Second question ( i know... greedy )
Why, when i run my code (in codeblocks) i get nothing returned?
[Codeblocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtSIv.png)

But, when i run it in leetcode, i get the expected results?
[Leetcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBtVZ.png)

Comment: You're not printing or returning anything to the outside world in your version - so how would it know what to "return"/show?

Comment: Your function `twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target)` will accept a vector, but **not** if it's an unnamed temporary.  Leetcode presumably didn't pass a temporary.  You are passing a temporary.  The issue has nothing to do with your IDE, but with the calling code.

Comment: Im returning the array in the Solutionclass, shouldnt that return the results?

Comment: It returns it to the caller, your main. But in there, you just throw it away

Comment: Since code around `Solution` on leetcode is much more complex and runs multiple test cases at once. Most probably some testing framework is used and temporary value is not used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if the signature of `twoSum` has a `vector<int>&` parameter, you're not allowed to call `twoSum` with `{2,7,11,15}` as an argument, because that would require the creation of a temporary vector, and `vector<int>&` is not allowed to bind to that temporary. You would need to add `const` to the referenced type. This will be the case regardless of whether the code is being compiled on LeetCode or in your local environment.

The thing about LeetCode is that you can't actually see the code that's used to call `twoSum`. Perhaps that code looks more like the following:

```
vector<int> nums;
// load input values into `nums`
vector<int> result = solution.twoSum(nums, target);
```

In this case, there is no temporary, and the reference can bind to `nums` without any issues.